# Django-Allauth Facebook integration - Ask for permission to post to User's wall separately

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth in my Django application.

Every user has an option to connect his/her Facebook account to their existing account.
I was able to to do this by adding allauth's connect process.

```
<a href='{% provider_login_url "facebook" process="connect" %}'>
   Connect with Facebook
</a>
```

At this point, I don't want to ask for permission to post to the user's wall.

```
#settings.py

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk'
    }
}
```

All goes well and the user can connect a Facebook account.

But, is there a way to ask for permission to post on the user's wall separately? I don't want to ask for publish_actions permissions above.

How do I do this using django-allauth?

How do I ask for publish_actions permission separately? Can this be done using django-allauth? Because I am guessing this requires re-declaring 'SCOPE' for 'facebook' SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS in settings.py.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved it. Turns out that django allauth saves the settings as JSON in the DOM element **#allauth-facebook-settings**. You just have to modify this json and pass to the allauth facebook init function. When the user clicks to enable a feature which requires 'publish_actions' permission, I call a Javascript function:

```
function modify_permissions() {
    var json = JSON.parse($("#allauth-facebook-settings").html());
    json["loginOptions"]["scope"] = "email, publish_actions";
    allauth.facebook.init(json);
}
```

Now, if you try to connect a FB account from that page, django allauth will ask for 'publish_actions' permission too.

Answer (score 0):

In the `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDER` setting provided by django allauth http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#facebook You would need to change the following section to include any extra permission you need

`SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'publish_actions'], # add your permissions here
            'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
            ...
    }
}`